# RecyclerView notifyItemChanged(position) is not updating that row in position

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

Data Model

```
public class Model implements Serializable {
@SerializedName("shortlisted_state") @Expose private boolean shortlistState;

public void setShortlistState(boolean shortlistState) {
  this.shortlistState = shortlistState;
}

public boolean getShortlistState() {
  return shortlistState;
}
}
```

on item click of the recyclerview, go to another activity with startActivityForResult with this way.

```
@Override public void onItemClick(View view, int position) {
Intent i = new Intent(getActivity(), ListingDetailActivity.class);
i.putExtra(ListingDetailActivity.KEY_LISTING, (Serializable) adapter.getListings());
i.putExtra(ListingDetailActivity.POSITION, position);
startActivityForResult(i, ACTION_DETAIL);
}
```

then after user has made changes and return to list activity,

```
@Override public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
if (requestCode == ACTION_DETAIL && resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
  final ArrayList<Integer> positions = data.getIntegerArrayListExtra("position");
  final boolean[] states = data.getBooleanArrayExtra(ListingDetailActivity.KEY_LISTING);
  for (int i = 0; i < positions.size(); i++) {
    adapter.updateChanges(positions.get(i), states[i]);
  }
 }
}
```

in RecyclerView adapter, I notifyItemChange like this,

```
public void updateChanges(int position, boolean status) {
listings.get(position).setShortlistState(status);
notifyItemChanged(position);
}
```

listings is ArrayList listings from above model clas.

But the RecyclerView is not updating that row. Is there something I am missing?

Comment: I think you confirm whether the value is really changed after setShortlistState. Could you show me detail sources about 'listings' and 'setShortlistState'?

Comment: where are you getting data from in list, and how are you updating data in list?

Comment: I think I found the bug and why it is happening. I put a flag whether is user is not login or not. When user is logged in, the adapter is not checking from listing model, but from database.